# How do you find the exact reason for Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value?

Tags: swift, xcode

I keep getting this error. I know why I am getting it but having trouble finding it. Is there a trick in Xcode to finding the exact variable that is causing this?

[image: Error Image]

In the image above it shows the error on the line that passes the data from the cell to the button. Would this error be located in the actual cell or in the button section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let tag = sender.tag
```

This line of code is dangerous because by the time your code is running. The `tag` that specify the row of the cell maybe just invisible or even worse your datasource is already changed so that you won't get the cell and instead you get the `nil`.

I'll just quote from the document of the method `cellForRow(at:)`.

```
Return Value
An object representing a cell of the table, or nil if the cell is not visible or indexPath is out of range.
```

Check https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614983-cellforrow for more details.

Comment: Thanks. That has to be the issue. Been searching the past 4 hours for alternative ways to do this. Do you know of any? I tried superview and that didn't work.

Comment: I can't tell only by the code snippet you provided @BTR199234